# Picasso's image loading using fit() method

Tags: android, picasso

If I am using `Picasso's fit()` method in loading images from online, do I have to consider using `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` options to reduce the size of an image? I read from other stackoverflow's question ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147501/custom-listview-with-many-images-gets-out-of-memory-exception)) that:

> You can also make use of the BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize
>   options to reduce the size of an image while it is loaded, rather than
>   loading in the entire image and then creating a small copy, which
>   wastes time and memory.

Do I have to do it after using `fit()`? Or it is already done by `Picasso`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `fit()` and explicit calls to `resize()` (or `resizeDimen`) will use `inSampleSize` automatically when it is appropriate to do so.

Because `inSampleSize` should be a power of two for best performance and quality, your image needs to be at least twice as large as the target size for this to occur.